# android getting the number of cameras on a device

Tags: android, android-camera

I am getting a peculiar error  when trying to count the number of cameras.

The error is:

> "Call requires API level 9(curret min is 5):android.hardware.Camera#getNumberOfCameras"

```
package com.example.cam_test2;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if   (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);

        TextView myText = new TextView(this);

        myText.setText("yes");

        lView.addView(myText);

        setContentView(lView);
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);

        TextView myText = new TextView(this);
        myText.setText("no");

        lView.addView(myText);

        setContentView(lView);

        return false;
    }
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    int camNum;
    camNum=Camera.getNumberOfCameras() ;///////error here///////////

    TextView myTextView = null;
    myTextView.setText("There are " + camNum+" cameras availabe");

    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
}
```

Comment: Why did you not bother to post the error?

Comment: Please feel free to actually log the exception that you are getting.

Comment: What is this "peculiar error"? Do you have a LogCat output?

Comment: I just edited my post and added the error..

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a duplicate of the one I posted.

Comment: `Call requires API level 9(curret min is 5)` what do you not understand?

Comment: I had my android:minSDKVersion set at 5. I thought you could have the sdk version set as early as you wanted and it would still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask for permission to use the camera in your AndroidManifest file.

Put this in the root of `<manifest>`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

You also need to make sure you have the correct minimum API level specified.  This class was introduced in API level 9, so you need to specify 9 or higher as your minimum API level:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
```

Comment: I had my android:minSDKVersion set at 5.  I thought you could have the sdk version set as early as you wanted and it would still work?

Comment: @codenamejupiterx nope.  For a feature to work, it must have the minimum API level supported.  You're thinking of the recommended API level.  The reason they make the distinction is to allow developers to make graceful degradation of some features possible.  For example, multiple cameras vs. a single camera.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could post your Manifest file, but I think you need to raise the minSdkVersion in that.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```